# Python Selenium: Can get web's element but cannot get the text in it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, getattribute

https://www.futunn.com/en/stock/FUTU-US
This webpage, Say I would like to get float value
[image]

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
PATH='C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.futunn.com/en/stock/FUTU-US')
freeflowtickers=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[4]/div[9]/div[4]/div[2]")
print(freeflowtickers)
print(freeflowtickers.text)
```

Then run it, in the console, you get

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="08bc2133e5e3b6911cea32c6750833a8", element="e38cb418-2e37-428d-af4b-e01dd3e691ae")>
```

But after it no text is aquired.

How could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

To print the text ***64.11M*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Float']//following-sibling::div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Float']//following-sibling::div[1]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.futunn.com/en/stock/FUTU-US")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='stock-detail-btn']/i"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Float']//following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.futunn.com/en/stock/FUTU-US")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='stock-detail-btn']/i"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Float']//following-sibling::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't the cleanest solution but I just tested it and it's working.

```
float_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/section[1]/div[4]/div[9]/div[4]')
number = float_element.text.split("\n")[1]
```

I've grabbed the xpath of the parent div tag which contains two lines of text "Float" and the number which are separated by a newline.

Comment: I tested it and found that I have to manually hit the drop down button to show the float data. Did you get there data without manually hit that drop down button?

Comment: I believe not, as it's dynamic content you'll have to use selenium to find the dropdown element and click it.